# scrollbar action in java

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java.
I have a text area and I have set only the vertical scrollbar to that text area. I'm appending data for every 1 minute to the text area. The problem is when new data appends to the text area the scrollbar will move up. To see the new data, every time I have to drag the scroll bar, but that is not the requirement. The scrollbar should not move up but should move down. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the caret location to the last position everytime you append:

```
textArea.setCaretLocation(textArea.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
JTextArea display= new JTextArea();
JScrollPane scroll =new JScrollPane(display);

scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener(){
    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e){
        JTextArea textArea = (JTextArea)e.getSource();
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength()); 
    }
});
```

This way it will be fully automated.

Comment: I imagine this will also fully restrict scrolling, which might not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textArea.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

and then use *append* as you currently do.